# Python adding list to the values of a dictionary TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to compare two files and then write to a dictionary "dns_dic" the final result and I am getting this error:

Here is the script I am using:

```
g  = open('/data/data/A.1/ap2014-2dom.txt','r')
f = open('/data/data/A.1/test','r')

dns_dic=defaultdict(set)
d = defaultdict(set)
psl = PublicSuffixList()

for line in g:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    domain,bl_date= line.split('|')
    bl_date = int(bl_date)
    if domain in d:
        d[domain].add(bl_date)
    else:
        d[domain] = set([bl_date])

for n, line in enumerate(f):

    line = line.strip('')
    try:
        jdata = json.loads(line)
        dom = psl.get_public_suffix(jdata.get('rrname'))
    except:
        pass
    if dom in d:
        if dom not in dns_dic:
            for i in d[domain]:
                if jdata.get('time_first') <= i <= jdata.get('time_last'):
                    ip = jdata.get('rdata') # ip one or more ips in a list 
                    if dom in dns_dic:
                        dns_dic[dom].add(ip)
                    else:
                        dns_dic[dom] = set(ip)

print dns_dic
```

This is how g looks like:

```
0001211.com|1407101455
000a.biz|1399553282
000a.biz|1400084462
000a.biz|1400243222
```

and this is how f looks like:

```
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1400243400,"time_first":1388645949,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1389133600,"time_first":1389133600,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
{"rrname": "0001211.com.","time_last":1407101755,"time_first":1389074193,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this error? I think it is because I am adding list of ip(rdata) to the dns_dic , but I am not sure and I could not find a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to put a *list* into your set:

```
dns_dic[dom].add(ip)
```

`ip` is a list here; it is taken from `jdata`:

```
ip = jdata.get('rdata')
```

where it is defined as a list:

```
"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]
```

The contents of a set must be hashable, and lists are not.

You probably wanted to use [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) instead to add all *elements* of that list:

```
dns_dic[dom].update(ip)
```

Renaming the variable to `ips` (plural) would reflect better that it is a list.

You are already using a `defaultdict(set)` object for `dns_dic`, so there is no need to test for `dom in dns_dic`; you can use `update()` always:

```
if jdata.get('time_first') <= i <= jdata.get('time_last'):
    dns_dic[dom].update(jdata.get('rdata', []))
```

If you want to actually build such a set, you'll need to remove the following line:

```
if dom not in dns_dic:
```

as that means you are **ignoring** further entries in that domain.

That makes your second loop:

```
for n, line in enumerate(f):
    line = line.strip('')
    try:
        jdata = json.loads(line)
    except ValueError:
        continue  # ignore invalid or empty lines
    dom = psl.get_public_suffix(jdata.get('rrname'))
    for i in d.get(domain, []):
        if jdata['time_first'] <= i <= jdata['time_last']:
            dns_dic[dom].update(jdata['rdata'])
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. This works but does not add the next ip for the same domain to the dictionary as a value. So, using this I will only get one ip as a value while some keys has more than one value. that I s why I used add

Comment: @Mee: you are only updating `dns_dic[dom]` when *not yet in the dictionary*: `if dom not in dns_dic:`.

Comment: I see your point. But what I am trying to do, is check if it is there then just add the list to the existing list, else create the entry. your current code only keeps one item in the value

Comment: @Mee: your sample data only contains 2 domains and one unique ip address. The output produced from your sample data is correct for the limited dataset.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, Now my problem is solved. I realized that the first check for dom being in dns_dic is also extra and that was why I was getting only one ip in my value list.